# Finding perfect square in a list

Tags: python

```
l = [x**0.5 for x in range(101)]
print l
```

This code outputs:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903, 3.0, 3.162277660168379, 3.3166247903554, 3.4641016151377544, 3.605551275463989, 3.7416573867739413, 3.872983346207417, 4.0, 4.123105625617661, 4.242640687119285, 4.358898943540674, 4.47213595499958, 4.58257569495584, 4.69041575982343, 4.795831523312719, 4.898979485566356, 5.0, 5.0990195135927845, 5.196152422706632, 5.291502622129181, 5.385164807134504, 5.477225575051661, 5.567764362830022, 5.656854249492381, 5.744562646538029, 5.830951894845301, 5.916079783099616, 6.0, 6.082762530298219, 6.164414002968977, 6.244997998398398, 6.324555320336758, 6.4031242374328485, 6.48074069840786, 6.557438524302, 6.6332495807108, 6.708203932499369, 6.782329983125268, 6.855654600401044, 6.928203230275509, 7.0, 7.0710678118654755, 7.14142842854285, 7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518, 7.3484692283495345, 7.416198487095663, 7.483314773547883, 7.54983443527075, 7.615773105863909, 7.681145747868608, 7.745966692414834, 7.810249675906654, 7.874007874011811, 7.937253933193772, 8.0, 8.06225774829855, 8.12403840463596, 8.18535277187245, 8.246211251235321, 8.306623862918075, 8.366600265340756, 8.426149773176359, 8.48528137423857, 8.54400374531753, 8.602325267042627, 8.660254037844387, 8.717797887081348, 8.774964387392123, 8.831760866327848, 8.888194417315589, 8.94427190999916, 9.0, 9.055385138137417, 9.1104335791443, 9.16515138991168, 9.219544457292887, 9.273618495495704, 9.327379053088816, 9.38083151964686, 9.433981132056603, 9.486832980505138, 9.539392014169456, 9.591663046625438, 9.643650760992955, 9.695359714832659, 9.746794344808963, 9.797958971132712, 9.848857801796104, 9.899494936611665, 9.9498743710662, 10.0]
```

I only want to print perfect squares. What do I need to add to code?

Comment: Or just `n = 101; print([x*x for x in range(int(n**0.5)+1)])`, since we already know only `1*1`, `2*2`, `3*3`... works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output I wanted to get was `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]`
and I specifically wanted to do it using Lambda Function. I was going through old posts to improve and saw that best answer is suggested by @Holle van though I didn't like this `int(x**0.5) == x**0.5` part so combining few answers I came up with a new solution.

```
>>> [x for x in range(101) if x**0.5 % 1 == 0]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?:

```
[num for num in l if num == int(num)]
```

Answer (score 1):

since simple list comprehension looks ugly we can define utility function like

```
import math


def is_perfect_square(number):
    square_root = math.sqrt(number)
    square_root_floor = int(square_root)
    return square_root_floor * square_root_floor == number
```

then using built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function like

```
perfect_squares = filter(is_perfect_square, range(101))
```

- on **Python 2** `perfect_squares` will be a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of desired objects,
- on **Python 3** [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) and we need to convert it to `list` manually:

  ```
  perfect_squares = list(filter(is_perfect_square, range(101)))
  ```

finally:

```
>>> perfect_squares == [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

add a condition to the list comprehension, to make a one liner (without creating the list first, and then checking it)

```
l = [x for x in range(101) if int(x**0.5) == x**0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do the trick:

```
[x**0.5 for x in range(101) if x**0.5 % 1 == 0]
```